# Make a reference within a Finite State Machine

Tags: uml

I'm "drawing" a Finite State Machine, it should be UML-compliant. I have one state(A) where many transistion from many states(lets say: B,C,D,E) end. Instead of drawing a transistion from every state to A, I want(for clarity) to make a reference from B to Ref, and from C to Ref, and at end make a transistion from Ref to A. See the picture:

How to do this in a UML compliant way?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cite Superstructures ptc-13-09-05 p. 10:

> A metaclass may appear on many diagrams, but takes a primary role on only one diagram, which is the diagram adjacent to where the semantics of the metaclass are described.

So you can not do this unless your `Ref` appears in different diagrams. The reason is that in your green diagram the `Ref` were not clear to be the "same `Ref`" just by its name. So OMG put that (good) restriction on diagrams that a single element may occur only once on a single diagram.

[image]

Comment: I know that I don't can do it. The diagramm was just to clarify my concerns. The question was: How to do something like this in ONE Diagramm in a UML compliant way?!

edit: Furhtermore: This is NO Class Diagramm. I want to use a mechanism like a reference wihtin one Statemachine-Diagramm!

Comment: The diagram type is irrelevant. You can achieve the above by using diagram frames each containing `Ref` and one of the `B, C, ...` states.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but don't know how to implement/draw this inside a FSM-Diagramm... Can you give me an example?

Comment: OMG... So easy that I can't get it ;)
Thanks!